# How do i implement a login view as a jQueryUI dialog box in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, authentication, view, jquery-ui-dialog

I've seen a few example of similar things and i've also looked at the KiGG application which also uses a dialog box to display the login box. I'm pretty new to MVC but making some good progress and i'm looking to add a bit of candy for a demo i need to perform next week.

Does anyone have an simple example or could describe the steps i need to take to make a login view appear in a jQueryUI dialog box ?

I have some of the pieces i think ... I think i need a partial view to be in the master page (like Kigg) so that at anytime i hit a controller which needs authenication the master page will deal with it.

Any help would be appriecated.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a normal html form within your jQuery UI dialog. Example [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form).
2. Hook up [jQuery Form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to submit the form via ajax. Optionally, use [jQuery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) in combination. Example:

   function isValid(formData, jqForm, options) {
     return $(jqForm[0]).valid();
   }

   function loggedIn()
   {
       alert("You are logged in");
   }

   var formOptions = {
       beforeSubmit: isValid,
       success: loggedIn,
       url: '/your/mvc/action/on/login/controller',
       type: 'post'
     };

   var validateOptions = {
       submitHandler: function(form){
         jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit(formOptions);
         $("#dialog").dialog();
       },
       messages: {
         email: "Email is required",
         password: "Password required"
       }
     };

   $("#loginform").validate(validateOptions);
3. Create a login action on your account controller returning JsonResult and post your form to this action (should be https).